# Activity returns with "0" in requestCode

Tags: android, android-intent

I don't know where I am going wrong. This could be a trivial error, but i am not able to figure it out.

form my first activity I am starting another activity for result:

```
Intent ccard_intent= new Intent(this, create_ccard.class);
startActivityForResult(ccard_intent,start_activity_for_ccard);
```

In the new Activity i return using:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("card_name", Card_name);
setResult(create_ccard.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

in onActivityResult of my first activity:

```
  protected void onActvityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    this.requestCode=requestCode;


    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "resume working switch case error" + requestcode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


   if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){

    flag=0;
   }
}
```

i am getting error0 at the place of requestCode?
Why??
where have i gone wrong??
it should be 788 as I am using it while tarting the activity.

thankyou!

Comment: Could you try printing the value of 'requestCode' before setting 'this.requestCode=requestCode;'?

Comment: how should I print this? but this has to be 0 because it is simple assignment, I don't think it will make any difference. the problem is why the intent is returning 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
startActivityForResult(ccard_intent,start_activity_for_ccard);
```

is the one that actually determines what value you get in

```
this.requestCode=requestCode;
```

See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Seeing your Toast code

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "resume working switch case error" + requestcode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

my best guess would be that since you're changing the case (using `requestcode` instead of `requestCode`), you're getting the wrong value printed out by the `Toast`

Also (following lengthy discussion): your method signature is wrong. It reads

```
protected void onActvityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

and should be

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

which explains, rather neatly, why your requestCode never changed its value from 0.

Comment: i have a switch case in onResume which depends upon the requestCode

Comment: how should i do that,there is some error  requestCode, hence my switch case does not work!

Comment: its value that i get in the toast

Comment: i don't have any error as such, the activity returns successfully, i tried putting some values in the intent to be returned, but they are not returned as well

Comment: is it due to nullpointerexception?
i something in my Logcat 
it shouldn't have been there

Comment: Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "resume working switch case error" + requestcode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: my switch case depends upon requestcode,  requestcode is a global variable which i set to requestCode in onActivityResult

Comment: the code in my question is my code, in your review , i have modified one line, Toast message is after this.requestcode=requestCode 
and from what toast shows it is 0

Comment: no look requestcode(global variable) is another variable which i am setting to requestCode in onActivityResult. 
and then I use that value in toast!! As it shows 0, both of them should have value 0 and hence the Activity returns with requestCode=0 which is what i dont want, it has to be 788

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26047/discussion-between-user2056245-and-digcamara)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
setResult(create_ccard.RESULT_OK);
```

to

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

Comment: @user2056245 this is because the `RESULT_OK` field is inherited due to it not being private. You haven't really changed anything.

Comment: @user2056245 not entirely sure. What is `error0` anyways? It's not a field. If it is part of the stack trace, you may want to post that. Also, I did notice that you never send back the Intent. `setResult(create_ccard.RESULT_OK,i);` is probably what you wanted.

Comment: i just try viewing the result (requestCode) by using a Toast. it shows error0 there